# Cannot connect to hive through scala in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I tried to connect to hive and select some data for test in spark sql by scala, but I failed to do so. The code I use is as follows:

```
object LoadHive {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
if (args.length < 2) {
  println("Usage: [sparkmaster] [tablename]")
  exit(1)
}
   val master = args(0)
   val tableName = args(1)
   val sc = new SparkContext(master, "LoadHive", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
   val hiveCtx = new HiveContext(sc)
   val input = hiveCtx.sql("FROM src SELECT key, value")
   val data = input.map(_.getInt(0))
   println(data.collect().toList)
 }
}
```

And the exception log is as follows:

```
16/11/28 07:25:34 WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.defaultOverrides(HiveContext.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.scala.LoadHive$.main(LoadHive.scala:19)
    at com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.scala.LoadHive.main(LoadHive.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.EncodingUtils.setBit(BIZ)B
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.PrivilegeGrantInfo.setCreateTimeIsSet(PrivilegeGrantInfo.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.PrivilegeGrantInfo.<init>(PrivilegeGrantInfo.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles_core(HiveMetaStore.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles(HiveMetaStore.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 37 more
```

I feel very confused about this, has anybody met this issue? Do I need to built the spark with hive to solve this issue? I think the spark already support hive. The spark version I use is 1.6.1. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To verify that Spark is working with Hive run

```
./bin/spark-sql --master local[*]
```

and execute any sql query (e.g. select count(1) from src;)

Note that Spark has to be built with Hive support and `hive-site.xml` exists on classpath.

Comment: I have already solved the problem, it is due to multiple thrift version in the classpath. But also thank you.